# How to split a JSON object into a list (GSON, Android)?

Tags: android, retrofit

I have some json response:

```
{
  "address": "0a1ac9b9a342c3600995845eec7254df664d6aa9",
  "workers": {
    "desktop-380h0l6": {
      "worker": "desktop-380h0l6",
      "hashrate": "92.2 MH/s",
      "reportedHashRate": "81.6 MH/s",
      "validShares": 81,
      "invalidShares": 0,
      "staleShares": 3,
      "workerLastSubmitTime": 1499408997,
      "invalidShareRatio": 0
    },
    "eco-001": {
      "worker": "eco-001",
      "hashrate": "121.1 MH/s",
      "reportedHashRate": "130.1 MH/s",
      "validShares": 109,
      "invalidShares": 0,
      "staleShares": 0,
      "workerLastSubmitTime": 1499408985,
      "invalidShareRatio": 0
    },
    "eco-002": {
      "worker": "eco-002",
      "hashrate": "114.1 MH/s",
      "reportedHashRate": "108.5 MH/s",
      "validShares": 102,
      "invalidShares": 0,
      "staleShares": 1,
      "workerLastSubmitTime": 1499408993,
      "invalidShareRatio": 0
    },
    "eco-003": {
      "worker": "eco-003",
      "hashrate": "125.5 MH/s",
      "reportedHashRate": "129.6 MH/s",
      "validShares": 111,
      "invalidShares": 0,
      "staleShares": 3,
      "workerLastSubmitTime": 1499408969,
      "invalidShareRatio": 0
    }
}
```

I need to split the object "workers" into list. How can I do this? In my project I use Retrofit with GSON. I thought that code like this would help me, but I was wrong:

```
public class WorkersDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Workers> {
    @Override
    public Workers deserialize(JsonElement json,
                                             Type typeOfT,
                                             JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

        final JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
        List<Worker> list = new LinkedList<>();
        jsonObject.entrySet().forEach(new Consumer<Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> stringJsonElementEntry) {
                list.add(context.deserialize(stringJsonElementEntry.getValue(), Workers.class));
            }
        });

        Workers w =new Workers();
        w.setWorkers(list);
        return w;
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you have control of the JSON source? If yes, making `workers` an array will be much easier. The key is  not need because it is already in the object.

Comment: @Joshua
Unfortunately, I haven't such control. Do you have some ideas how to do split?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just deserialize it to a `Map` and then collect its values into a list?

Workers.java:

```
public class Workers {
    @SerializedName("address")
    private String mAddress;

    @SerializedName("workers")
    private Map<String, Worker> mWorkers;

    /* ... */
}
```

And then:

```
Workers workers = new Gson().fromJson(json, Workers.class);
List<Worker> = new ArrayList<>(workers.getWorkers().values());
```